# How can I use Reflection to get the value of a Static Property of a Type without a concrete instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, reflection

Consider the following class:

```
public class AClass : ISomeInterface
{
    public static int AProperty
    {
   get { return 100; } 
    }
}
```

I then have another class as follows:

```
public class AnotherClass<T>
   where T : ISomeInterface
{

}
```

Which I instance via:

```
AnotherClass<AClass> genericClass = new  AnotherClass<AClass>();
```

How can I get the static value of AClass.AProperty from within my genericClass without having a concrete instance of AClass?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like

```
typeof(AClass).GetProperty("AProperty").GetValue(null, null)
```

will do. Don't forget to cast to `int`.

Documentation link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx (they've got example with static properties, too.) But if you know exactly `AClass`, you can use just `AClass.AProperty`.

If you are inside `AnotherClass<T>` for `T = AClass`, you can refer to it as `T`:

```
typeof(T).GetProperty("AProperty").GetValue(null, null)
```

This will work if you know for sure that your `T` has static property `AProperty`. If there is no guarantee that such property exists on any `T`, you need to check the return values/exceptions on the way.

If only `AClass` is interesting for you, you can use something like

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(AClass))
    n = AClass.AProperty;
else
    ???
```

Comment: Great. The only issue I have now discovered is that I cannot define the static property in the Interface, which it needs to do. I guess I could add a non static property and a static property returning the same value, one for the instance to use and one to be referenced on the type? Or is there another way round it?

Comment: Alternatively I could get the non static property using new T().AProperty , but this seems like it would be bad practice. What do you think?

Comment: @Stewart: Well, constructing a new `T` might be expensive. It's a pity that interfaces cannot include static things, indeed.

Comment: @Stewart: maybe (if your design allows that) you can split the `AClass` into a static and non-static part, and make the static part into a separate class with instance methods/properties? The instances of former non-static `AClass` will then have a static reference to a single instance of the new class.

Answer (score 1):

First get the generic type of your `AnotherClass` instance.

Then get the static property.

Then get the property's static value.

```
// I made this sealed to ensure that `this.GetType()` will always be a generic
// type of `AnotherClass<>`.
public sealed class AnotherClass<T>
{
    public AnotherClass(){
        var aPropertyValue = ((PropertyInfo)
                this.GetType()
                    .GetGenericArguments()[0]
                    .GetMember("AProperty")[0])
            .GetValue(null, null);
    }
}
```

Recognizing, of course, that it isn't possible to ensure that "AProperty" will exist, because interfaces don't work on static signatures, I removed `ISomeInterface` as being irrelevant to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you're binding the flags you want
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags